# Google Sheets: Many to Many Table Join

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a sheet to determine the amount of overlapping hours for employees.

I have one table with timeclock data for the Employees.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9AuH.png)

And another with timeclock data for their Support Staff.

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwGFM.png)

This is the desired output. Each row from table A has all the date matches from table B. From here I would compute the number of overlapping hours in the final column and then roll that up into another sheet.

[Table 3, Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbDS1.png)

(apologies for image links, I can't post inline images yet)

Sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/196Cdg2d9vF7izoPEoYO11U_49RAoM07_N6AzLrEYCI4/edit?usp=sharing) Please let me know if you have any ideas for me!

I know its a combination of QUERY, ARRAYFORMULA, FILTER and more but I just can't find the right combo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of doing this type of join using only built-in functions:

```
=arrayformula(lambda(employee,support,
lambda(datecomp,
lambda(rows,
{vlookup(index(rows,,1),{row(employee),employee},sequence(1,columns(employee),2),false),
vlookup(index(rows,,2),{row(support),support},sequence(1,columns(support),2),false)})(
split(filter(datecomp,datecomp<>""),"|")))(
flatten(if(index(employee,,1)=transpose(index(support,,1)),row(employee)&"|"&transpose(row(support)),))))(
Employee!A1:D6,Support!A1:E5))
```

There's a lot going on here, but the basic idea is that we are comparing the date columns of each table against each other in a 2D IF array, and where the dates match we are obtaining the row index of each table. After some manipulations we can use these row indexes on each table in two side-by-side VLOOKUPs to obtain the joined table.

Comment: By jove you've done it! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DMac,

I wrote myself a QUERY replacement custom function that uses real SQL select syntax.

For your data it looks something like (You need a tab called employee and a tab called support for this to work) :

```
=gsSQL("select * from employee full join support on employee.date = support.date")
```

See my test worksheet: (line 164 on gsSqlTest sheet)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Zmyk7a7u0xvICrxen-c0CdpssrLTkHwYx6XL00Tb1ws/edit?usp=sharing

You need to add one Apps Script file to your sheet to give you the custom function:
https://github.com/demmings/gsSQL/blob/main/dist/gssql.js

For more help using more features see:
https://github.com/demmings/gsSQL

For example, changing the column titles, it would be like:
**select employee.name as name ....** (rest of your select).

Comment: No doubt this is a great solution, thank you. I opted for the scriptless version but will keep this in my back pocket, thank you!